# TranslateTransition showing white background when i use Parent As Node in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am using Translate Transition in my application but the Problem is when i Run my application it will show white background but i want the background stay Transparent.

[image]

but i need when i translate my application it will show no background
[image]

I am using this Code

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
     TranslateTransition X=new TranslateTransition(Duration.millis(2000),Parentroot);
        X.setFromX(40);
        X.setToX(0);
        X.play();
```

Comment: Animate the `x` property instead or use `TRANSPARENT` stage style...

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

```
stage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

Using this code, your problem will definitely solve.